# Android - Image is not showing in ImageView and not save to gallery from camera

Tags: android, imageview, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I try to get image from camera and set it to Image View and save to gallery, the picture is successfully captured, but the picture is not showing to Image View and not saved to gallery. I don't know where is the problem.

Many post here I've tried but still don't solve my problem.

This is my code

Definition:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private String id_sales, pilihanUploadPp, imagePath;
private EditText namaEdt, usernameEdt, notelpEdt, emailEdt;
private ProgressDialog progress;
private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
private SessionManager sessionManager;
private int CAMERA_PERM_CODE = 1;
private static final int IMG_REQUEST1 = 100, IMG_REQUEST2 = 200;
private ImageView pp_img;
```

onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ubah_profil);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

        namaEdt = findViewById(R.id.nama_edit_edt);
        usernameEdt = findViewById(R.id.username_edit_edt);
        notelpEdt = findViewById(R.id.telp_edit_edt);
        emailEdt = findViewById(R.id.email_edit_edt);
        pp_img = findViewById( R.id.pp_edit_iv );
        Button ubahBtn = findViewById(R.id.ubah_edit_btn);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setTitle("Ubah Profil");

        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionbar != null;
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getIntentDataFromFragmentProfil();
        ubahBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        pp_img.setOnClickListener( this );
    }
```

onClick method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.ubah_edit_btn:
                updateProfil();
            break;
            case R.id.pp_edit_iv:
                selectImage();
            break;
        }
    }
```

selectImage method:

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Kamera", "Galeri", "Batal"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( UbahProfilActivity.this );
        builder.setTitle( "Ubah Foto Profil" );
        builder.setItems( items , (dialog , which) -> {
            if (items[which].equals( "Kamera" )){
                pilihanUploadPp = "Kamera";
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( UbahProfilActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    cameraIntent();
                } else {
                    reqCameraPerms();
                }
            }
        } );
        builder.show();
    }
```

cameraIntent method:

```
private void cameraIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        if (intent.resolveActivity( getPackageManager()) != null){
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ioex){
                Toast.makeText( this , "Error: "+ioex , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            if (photoFile!=null){
                Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( this , "com.example.bismillah.newsahabatauto2000.Activity.provider" , photoFile );
                intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
                startActivityForResult( intent, IMG_REQUEST1 );
            }
        }
    }
```

createImageFile method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir =
                getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        imagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

and finally onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode , resultCode , data );
        try{
            if (requestCode==IMG_REQUEST1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                if (data !=null && data.getExtras() !=null){
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get( "data" );
                    pp_img.setImageBitmap( imageBitmap );
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText( this , "Error: "+e , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the image is successfully captured?

Comment: when I click "pp_img" the device is entering camera mode, then I did capture the picture. But when back to activity the Image View is still no picture and my gallery is still no picture too @Ümañgßürmån

Comment: Please add a break point in onActivityResult and check what you get in data

Comment: The [description of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) states that when you specify EXTRA_OUTPUT, you give up on `(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get( "data" )`. Please note that *If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image*. If **pp_img** is not very small, the quality of this bitmap will not be enough, and you will need to load the image from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its working for me Perfectly,

private final static int CAMERA = 0, GALLERY = 1;

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private Uri selectedImage = null
```

private void onClickUploadPicture() {
        requestAppPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, new setPermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(int requestCode) {
                        new ImagePicker(CreateBusinessAccountActivity.this, new ImagePicker.onItemClick() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCameraClicked() {
                                displayCamera();
                            }

```
                        @Override
                        public void onGalleryClicked() {
                            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, GALLERY);
                        }
                    }).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(int requestCode) {
                    showSnackBar(toolbar, getString(R.string.please_grant_permission), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE,
                            getString(R.string.settings), () -> {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            });
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(selectedImage));

                glideUtils.loadCircleImageFromLocal("file://" + selectedImage, mBinding.companyLogo.ivUserImage);
                userData.setProfileOrLogoUri(selectedImage);
                mBinding.companyLogo.ivFlag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBinding.companyLogo.ivFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selected_check_with_green_circle);
                mBinding.companyLogo.tvFullName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.update_profile_pic));
            }
            break;
        case GALLERY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                assert data != null;
                selectedImage = data.getData();
                assert selectedImage != null;
                Log.e(TAG, selectedImage.toString());

                glideUtils.loadCircleImageFromLocal(new File(getRealPathFromURI(CreateBusinessAccountActivity.this, selectedImage)).getAbsolutePath(), mBinding.companyLogo.ivUserImage);
                userData.setProfileOrLogoUri(Uri.parse(getRealPathFromURI(CreateBusinessAccountActivity.this, selectedImage)));
                mBinding.companyLogo.ivFlag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBinding.companyLogo.ivFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selected_check_with_green_circle);
                mBinding.companyLogo.tvFullName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.update_profile_pic));
            }
            break;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) for capture, or add image from phone, and also crop it,
and for saving this works for me:

```
File file = null;


        String taskFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/myPhotos/" + sID[0] + sID[1];

        String sType = "";
        if (type == 1) {
            String time = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            sType = "start-" + sID[0] + sID[1] + time;  //sID is a String table
            file = new File(taskFolderPath, sType + ".jpg");


        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            OutputStream stream = null;
            stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,stream); //0 - min, 100 - max quality, true if success
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```